# Generate RadGrid in client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, radgridview

how we can create a RadGridView with client-side javascript codes in ASP.net & Telerik without datasource and addding columns and data programitically ?

Comment: The Telerik ASP.NET AJAX controls are, primarily, server controls, so you cannot create them entirely on the client. The answer below offers some ideas and you may also want to look into the Kendo UI suite as it offers pure client-side widgets.

Answer (score 0):

If you do all of these completely from client side code. My suggestion for this question would be like following - even if you don't have datasource for gridview, how you are going to have some data for `gridview`, ultimately `grid` is meant to have some `data` to display, otherwise there is no use of it.

So if you are intended to know, how to bind data from other source, say a `web service` or `web api` or `.json` file, you can do all of these and specify columns in `javascript` directly.

Following link explains that deeply - http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-client-side-binding.html

Comment: I need to add columns into table with Javascript , I have my Data through a PageMethod with Ajax with out post back into my table.
and gridview's data isnt fixed and its changed even in columns

Comment: @SiamandMa'roufi , you can trap `RadGrid1_RowDataBound` event in `js`, and set required columns as visible, as you have specified `gridview's data isnt fixed and its changed even in columns`, so even if you don't do the above ( show/hide columns), radgrid will have required set of column as received by `PageMethod via ajax.`

Comment: I know that but the column's quantity is not predicatedable for making a lot of them and make them unvisible for late uses.

Comment: @SiamandMa'roufi , i would suggest , give a try , the 1st comment of mine.